# How to get the debuggee's command line in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

Is there any extension command could to do so? I just want to the the whole command line including all parameters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Information like the command line args are stored in the [PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) (Process Environment Block).

You can find [a list of common commands here.](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html)

`!peb` will display the PEB.

Comment: Yes, this works well, even if there are many unrelated information in the output.  I just found another command `version` which could list the command line as well.

Comment: So many WinDbg commands available, and what they can display is encyclopaedic! Here's a good reference: http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html

Comment: The "version" command lists the command-line of the windbg process, not the command-line of the process you're debugging.

Comment: @alfa, you are right, in the case the debugge is launched by windbg, the command line for windbg hints the command line of the debuggee.

Comment: You may use the following command not to parse the whole output of "!peb":
`.shell -ci "!peb" findstr "CommandLine"`.

Answer (score -1):

try vercommand
it's a lot simpler than !peb
this is a good place to get you started:
http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#2_general_cmds

Comment: This doesn't work since it reports command line of WinDbg, not the debuggee if it is attached at runtime.