# Restart application with arguments

Tags: windbg

In WinDBG I can use `.restart` to restart the application, but is it possible to specify command line arguments?

I already tried `.restart arg1 arg2`, but got syntax error.

Any ideas?

Comment: could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224834/how-to-get-the-debuggees-command-line-in-windbg

Comment: no, you need to modify PEB and then restart process

Answer (score 0):

.restart is only useful if  windbg opened the application if you had attached to the application .restart wont work so better close the windbg instance open a command prompt  and do windbg app arg1 arg2 ....