# View the exact command that was used when running the application

Tags: windbg

I am trying to know what is the exact command that GoPro Fusion Studio is using because I tried to run the command line to do a 360video stitching like this

```
"C:\Program Files\GoPro\Fusion Studio 1.3\FusionStudio_x64.exe" -d C:\PythonStuff\TestChapters\ --width 3072 --videoCodec 1 --pc 1 --blending 0 --projection 0 --stabilization 2 --iq 0 -o C:\PythonStuff\TestChapters\Out
```

if you want to know more you can look at this [thread](https://community.gopro.com/t5/GoPro-Apps-for-Desktop/Command-Line-amp-Chapter-File-Rendering/td-p/245065)

So, you can see that the executable is indeed has some commands to run and we can do that, its not officially supported though. But, its just that the Studio, GUI, isn't reliable. And when I use command line I am getting the stitching a bit weird, so I would like to know if I do it using the GUI, which is working properly when IT wants to and know that exact command.
So, I attached the process to winddbg and started to see the command output window but no command is being displayed when the rendering starts.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the debuggee's command line in WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224834/how-to-get-the-debuggees-command-line-in-windbg)

Answer (score 2):

For Each And Every Process the Process Environment Block holds the Command-line Passed to the program

you can view it like

```
C:\>cdb -c "dx @$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine;q" calc yakku bakku dakku | tail -4

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'dx @$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine;q'

@$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine : "calc yakku bakku dakku " [Type: _UNICODE_STRING]

    [<Raw View>]     [Type: _UNICODE_STRING]
quit:
```

testing live existing process like firefox

```
C:\>tasklist /Fi "ImageName eq firefox*"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
firefox.exe                   3396 Console                    1    116,092 K

C:\>cdb -p 3396

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86

0:018> dx @$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine
@$peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine : ""C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --channel="2908.20.
328654377\1778207522" -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 3032 -prefsLen 15829 -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -parentBuildID 2
0181001155545 -greomni "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\omni.ja" -appomni "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\omn
i.ja" -appdir "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser" - 2908 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.2908" 3028 tab" [Type:
 _UNICODE_STRING]
    [<Raw View>]     [Type: _UNICODE_STRING]
0:018>
```